# Theorem 1.17 in Rudin's RCA

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

Here is theorem 1.17 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

> Let $f : X \to [0,\infty]$ be measurable. There exist simple measurable functions $s_n$ on $X$ such that (a) $0 \le s_1 \le s_2 \le ... \le f$ and (b) $s_n(x) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$ for every $x \in X$.

I am working through both Rudin's proof and [this](https://math.byu.edu/~bakker/m641w12/lec03.pdf) proof of the above theorem. I just want to go over a few things to make sure I understand everything.

First, I think I can see why $\varphi_n$ is a Borel function: both $[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})$ and $[n,\infty]$ are Borel sets, so the characteristic function on each is a Borel function; finally, the sum of Borel function is a Borel function, making $\varphi_n(t)$ a Borel function. Second, I think I can see that $\varphi_n(t) \to t$. Given $t \ge 0$ and $n \in \Bbb{N}$, there exists a nonnegative integer $k_n$ such that $k_n < t 2^{n} < k_n+1$ or $k_n 2^{-n} < t < k_n 2^{-n} + 2^{-n}$ and therefore $0 < t - k_n 2^{-n} < 2^{-n}$. But $\varphi_n(t) = k_n 2^{-n}$, so that taking the limit $n \to \infty$, we get $\varphi_n(t) \to t$. Doing the the same for $f(x) \ge 0$, we can show that $\varphi_n(f(x)) \to f(x)$ for every $x \in X$. Hopefully someone having greater familiarity with the subject and Rudin's book RCA will correct me if I am wrong.

However, I am at the moment having trouble seeing why $\{\varphi_n\}$ is a monotonically increasing sequence.

Comment: I believe that $\phi_n(t)$ is defined $$ \phi_n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n2^n-1} k2^{-n} 1_{\{t \in [k2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n})\}} + n 1_{\{t \in [n,\infty]\}}$$, is that correct?

Comment: @Michael In the linked pdf, the it is $[k2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n})$; the right endpoint isn't included.

Comment: @Michael I see that you edited your comment before I could make mine. Yes, that is the function. I probably should have type that in my OP. Sorry everyone.

Comment: I think the idea behind $\phi_n(t)$ nondecreasing in $n$, is that, for each $t \geq 0$, we have $t$ is in exactly one of the intervals $[k2^{-n} , (k+1)2^{-n})$ or $[n, \infty)$, and $\phi_n(t)$ takes the leftmost value on the  interval in which $t$ lies.  When we increase $n$, then $t$ either stays in an interval with leftmost value the same as before, or with a higher leftmost value.  So $\phi_n(t)$ cannot decrease when we increase $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an interval $I:=\left[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}\right)$, we have 
\begin{align*}
I&=\left[2k\cdot 2^{-(n+1)},(2k+2)\cdot 2^{-(n+1)}\right)\\
&=\left[2k\cdot 2^{-(n+1)},(2k+1)\cdot 2^{-(n+1)}\right)\bigcup\left[(2k+1)\cdot 2^{-(n+1)},(2k+2)\cdot 2^{-(n+1)}\right),
\end{align*} 
you may now see that for a typical interval of $\phi_{n+1}$, it belongs to either the left part or the right part of a typical interval of $\phi_{n}$, and if you compare the values that $\phi_{n+1}$ and $\phi_{n}$ taken over there, they are $l2^{-(n+1)}$ and $k2^{-n}$ respectively, if it were belonging to the left part, then $l=2k$, if it were right part, then $l=2k+1$, in either case, $\phi_{n+1}(x)\geq\phi_{n}(x)$ over there.